# How to kill a process in remote Ubuntu server using PHP?

Tags: php, ubuntu, command-line

Is there any command that I can run to kill a specific process in remote Ubuntu server using PHP?

Also is there any command to list all the PHP process running in a remote Ubuntu server?

I was using ,

> ps aux | grep php

to list all PHP process, after logged into remote machine using ssh. But then, is it possible to get process list from local machine itself?

Note: I am running some set of cron jobs every 15 mins. And keeping process ID for each in DB. There are scenarios that I need to kill certain process ID from my monitoring tool(in another server).

If there is any command, then that I can use in my PHP script to call.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question could be on askubuntu.

If you have an SSH access to your server you are logged onto it.

Then, you can do `sudo killall php` to kill all PHP process or `sudo kill <idprocess>`.

Note that if you have an Apache server running, it can create new processes. Turn Apache off can allow to do not create new processes.

EDIT:

According to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38737/ssh-login-with-clear-text-password-as-a-parameter?answertab=active#tab-top) you can use a package to give password directly without interactivity. Thanks to that, it is possible for your script to sign in on the server, then kill processes, and finally sign out.

Comment: I agree. But then, I need to kill from one server (say localhost) to remote server via code?. And why I asked here means, if suppose I may get some other solution using PHP too, since I need solution via code only.

Comment: I didn't understand that you need to do it remotely with a script, without be logged in using ssh.
A bash script could do that, no ? The script could sign in to the server and kill processes.

Comment: Added more details in the question.

Comment: To access to a remote server you'll need to be logged in. So from you localhost you should sign in to the second server (as explained in this answer). Otherwise, you should do an Interface with a soft that is listening on a port and where you can send request (same as ssh). So the easier thing to do is using SSH, even from you post to send commandline)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [posix_kill()](http://php.net/posix_kill) function to send any signal to a process. Depending on your privileges, you may or may not see the results you expect.

The `SIGKILL` constant will send (as you'd expect) SIGKILL.

You really shouldn't be executing anything involving a combination of `exec()` and `sudo` under any circumstances. It implies that your setup is vulnerable to a lot of potential nasty people.

Comment: The real question is not killing the process, this is doing it remotely. But indeed posix_kill seems useful.

Comment: The question is about doing it remotely with PHP - I know I'm just really answering how to do it locally with PHP, but PHP is designed to be called remotely. Just calling that script with `curl` should be fine, provided it already has authentication (which I assume is already present for the rest of the application)

Comment: PHP can be called remotely only using a Web server. So you can just create a Web interface with an Apache server (or other). This is like a little website, only for your use. With authentication of course.

Comment: Oh I see - I was interpreting the question wrong, I think, as if it was between two apache/php servers.